# What is the meaning of this sentence about inversion of control?

Tags: sentence-meaning

This sentence is very twisted. Can anyone break it down?

> It's not "inversion of control" if the control over whether there's inversion of control is not inverted

Answer (score 1):

It means that *a technique doesn't qualify as* true "inversion of control" if the control of a specific thing is not *also* inverted. The specific thing here is the determination of "whether there's inversion of control".

Simply put, IoC has to go all the way into the program's architecture to count (in this author's opinion).